# Firefox extension to block IndexedDB access from specific sites

Tags: database, firefox, security, privacy

I am looking for a [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) extension that allows the user to block IndexedDB reads/writes from user-defined sites.

IndexedDB is a form of locally stored data that websites can create on your computer.  Unfortunately, Firefox has no built-in option to delete this data.  Clearing the browser's cache will ***never*** delete this data.  This creates serious [privacy](/questions/tagged/privacy) issues, and possibly some [security](/questions/tagged/security) ones as well.

Any cost is acceptable for the add-on.  Any operating system is acceptable.  Open source or closed source is acceptable, but a *preference* (not requirement) for open source.

Must be compatible with Firefox 42 or later.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So is this the same as "LocalStorage" (which can e.g. be explored using the [Foundstone HTML5 Local Storage Explorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/foundstone-html5-local-storage/) addon) – and you're just using a different term for it? In that case, [Self-Destructing Cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/self-destructing-cookies/) might come in handy.

Comment: @Izzy No. That's for HTML5 Local Storage, which is ***yet another*** form of local storage that websites can create on your computer.  This article, http://csimms.botonomy.com/2011/05/html5-storage-wars-localstorage-vs-indexeddb-vs-web-sql.html , although outdated, has a good overview of just a few of the different technologies.

Comment: @Izzy If you aren't familiar with how the data is stored on the system, you can see IndexedDB storage by using the Storage Inspector, which is included as part of the Firefox Developer Tools (available in the default Firefox installation).  It only shows the IndexedDB storage for the current site, however.

Comment: Yuck, very local stuff, getting me confused. "DOM Storage", "LocalStorage" (see [these addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/search/?q=localstorage)) – and now another one. Nevermind, take a look at [Permissions Auto Registerer](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/permissions-auto-registerer/), seems to be your candidate. If not, [here're the alternatives](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/search/?q=indexeddb). None tried by me, hence no answer but a comment ;) If it fits, let me know and I make it a full-fledged answer.

Comment: Oh, another one: [PrivaConf](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/privaconf/). Quote: *disable Safebrowsing, search suggests, geo, visited links, **indexedDB** and trim referer.* Just doesn't sound as if it would do that per-site.

Comment: @Izzy Permissions Auto Registerer would be excellent, but it no longer works is Firefox 42.  I have not tried the other 5 extensions, but according to the descriptions, none of them will do the job.

Comment: It's shown compatible – but yes, I just saw that comment. Keep an eye on it, as that comment is pretty fresh (and the last version not that old), the dev might provide an update soon (fingers crossed).

Comment: @Izzy It is simple to completely disable IndexedDB (which is what PrivaConf does), but some sites use IndexedDB for useful functionality.  What I need is something that will block it on a per-site basis.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Page Info menu next to the location bar which shows the URL:

[image: disable offline storage in firefox]

> Maintain Offline Storage is a site permission. It used to be in the preferences UI, but was dropped in FF46. You now get to it per site via urlbar info icon > Right Arrow > More Information > Permissions
>
> This is meant to control indexedDB as far as I know (and it has said that in the user.js since the start over 2 years ago).

and enable the Storage Inspector from the Developer Tools settings to test:

[image: Storage Inspector]

and check the console to verify:

[image: IndexedDB Disabled in Firefox]

**References**

- [Firefox Page Info window | Firefox Help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-page-info-window?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Page+Info+window)
- [Using the Permissions API - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API)
- [ghacks issue  #173: investigate: site exceptions Maintain Offline Storage](https://github.com/ghacksuserjs/ghacks-user.js/issues/173)
- [Firefox and IndexedDB](https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/firefox-and-indexeddb.395113/)
- [Storage Inspector - Firefox Developer Tools | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector)
- [Dev.Opera — An Introduction to IndexedDB](https://dev.opera.com/articles/introduction-to-indexeddb/)
- [web-platform-tests/IndexedDB at master · w3c/web-platform-tests](https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/tree/master/IndexedDB)
- [dexie.js Samples](http://dexie.org/docs/Samples)